# AirPlay audio output

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, appletv, airplay, speakers

Ok, so I'm working in a new classroom with the following scenario I'm trying to solve.  I have a MacBook Air connected to a ceiling projector using AirPlay.  The thing I don't like with this is that the audio also plays out of the builtin speakers within the ceiling projector.  The speakers are quiet and just bad sounding.  I have a set of good computer speakers that I'd like to simply connect to my MacBook, but the audio automatically goes to the projector. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: Is the ceiling projector connected to an Apple TV?

Comment: Yes, the apple tv is connected to the projector via hdmi. There is an audio cable output from the projector.  I can plug the speakers into that but it results in awkward speaker placement up by the ceiling, dangling cords, and I can't easily access the volume control, but that's what I'm currently doing... I guess I could get a long hdmi to run up to the projector, but it seems like a messy option if I already have the apple tv setup.

Comment: I'm not sure if this approach only forwards the display to Apple TV, but you can give [Apple TV display mirroring](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204289#mirrormac) a try.

Comment: You don't have to send audio to the Apple TV just because AirPlay is using it, the Sound prefpane gives you the option of selecting a different audio output.

Comment: Uh, just a suggestion, put volume control in the menu bar using the check box in the Sound prefpane, then option-click it to select your desired speakers.